# Kusto: remove non-matching rows when using the parse operator

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm querying azure log analytics using Kusto, and extracting fields with the `parse` operator, then keeping only the records which parsed correctly:

```
traces
| parse message with "Search found " people " people in " groupCount " groups"
| where people != "" and groupCount != ""
| order by n desc
```

Is there a more terse way of parsing and dropping non-matching rows? If I am parsing out a lot of columns from a set of logs, maybe containing partial matches, this connascence between the `parse` and `where` gets fiddly.

By comparison, in SumoLogic, the `parse` operator automatically drops all rows which don't match a parsed pattern, which makes for really tidy pipelines:

```
*
| parse "Search found * people in * groups" as people, groupCount
| order by n desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's now a built in operator that will do this: `parse-where`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/parsewhereoperator

It has syntax just like `parse`, but will omit from its output any records which didn't match the parse pattern.

So the query:

```
traces
| parse message with "Search found " people " people in " groupCount " groups"
| where people != "" and groupCount != ""
| order by n desc
```

becomes:

```
traces
| parse-where message with "Search found " people " people in " groupCount " groups"
| order by n desc
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kusto: 'parse' operator does not auto-filter rows that does not match the provided pattern, and operator works as in mode of 'extend' - adding more columns.
If you would like to filter specific row - the recommendation is to use 'where' operator before the 'parse': this will also improve performance as 'parse' will have fewer rows to scan.

```
traces
| where message startswith 'Search found'
| parse message with "Search found " people " people in " groupCount " groups"
 ...
```

Comment: The problem is: that `where` clause is going to get pretty gnarly if I want to make sure I filter out log lines like `Search found 100 products in 10 groups`, or `Search found 10 people in 100ms`. It's going to end up as a `matches regex` filter, structured almost exactly the same as the `parse`, which introduces a troublesome connascence. If I change the `parse` I have to change the `where` accordingly or I'll get bogus results.

Comment: The idea is that you will use filter with only few keywords (to make it fast), while in parse you specify how you actually break the text into new columns.

Comment: Fair enough, it's a different approach from what I'm used to though: I'll just have to adjust I guess.